# My Android Studio does not recognised my smartphone

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, flutter

My Android Studio can't find my connected device. (No devise), in my case I am trying to run an application using Flutter (but the point is how to recognize my connected device). I have already enabled the "Developer Mode" in my phone.

#### When I try to run

> Error = No connected devices found; please connect a device, or see flutter.io/setup for getting started instructions.

#### I tried to use the virtual device, but didn't work (I have tried 3 virtual devices)

> Error = PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.

Because of the fact that my Ubuntu cannot see my smartphone, I tried to mount my USB device, but it was not possible.

How can I solve this issue?

### Environment Detail

I am using the following Ubuntu revision

No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
    Release:    17.10
    Codename:    artful

```
With Android Studio:

Android Studio 3.1
Build #AI-173.4670197, built on March 21, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.13.0-37-generic

And My smart phone is:

Lenovo A2016b30 with Android 6.0
```

Comment: Run `adb devices` to check it. Maybe you need to install drivers.

Comment: install drivers if has not installed yet otherwise restart the android studio. I also face this issue often even drivers are already present but for me restart the android studio works. Also check in sdk tools, Google USB driver must be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your phone, check in developer options that you have "USB debugging" enabled.

Also, it seems that you are missing SDK platform tools for your emulator, check in SDK manager that you have packages installed for your emulator's API level.